# Auto Updating Cell Values in Excel using VB

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 Excel files named September and October. The September file contains values from which the October file refers/links to using the formula:

```
=+B2+'C:\\[September.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1
```

so cell `B2` in October contains a value that is the sum of `B2` and `A1` which comes from the September file.

If I now create a November file, I would simply do a Save As on the October file and save the file as November.xlsx. However, this means that the November file is still referring to  values September.xlsx. Is there any way of automatically updating the cells in November.xlsx to refer to October, either upon creation or opening of the November file?

i.e. so November's formula would automatically update to `=+B2+'C:\[October.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1`.

Or making a Window form pop up when opening the file, asking the month it would like it to link to, the user would then enter in a month then all the cells in range would be updated.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try to write the updation code in the open event method of the excel.

Answer (score 2):

A simple find and replace will work with this kind of link.

You'll have to skip over cells that use the name as a label that you don't want to change.  You can also do this in vba by looking only at formulas.  Here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/534815/2521004) about how to do that.

[image]

Comment: I have tried the Find and Replace method but not as specifically as you have set it like above. The way it's currently being done is, after saving as to the newer month, in this case November, all that's been done is change the cell formula from the top cell e.g. =+B2+'C:\\[September.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1 to =+B2+'C:\\[October.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1 then simply doing a drag down to all the cells below (B3, B4, B5 etc) to change/update their formula to October.xlsx. Both options are fine I am just trying to learn new methods and make it so you don't have to modify anything in the newly created spreadsheet.

Comment: +1 the most easiest way :) @bertrix: But why do you need to drag the formula? If you do `Replace All` then it will find an replace all instances. Also if you change the `within` from `sheet` to `workbook` then it will change in all sheets as well.

Comment: @bertrix: Also to be sure that you don't replace some other text by mistake search for `\\[September.xlsx]` and replace with `\\[October.xlsx]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Workbook.ChangeLink` method.

```
expression.ChangeLink(Name, NewName, Type)
```

where `Name` is the existing file name, `NewName` is the new file name

To see it in action, try recording a macro while changing the link source manually, and examine the resulting code. Access it from `Data/Connections/Edit Links` menu

Probably the simplest implementation would be to write a macro to do the SaveAs and ChangeLink in one go.  Or leverage the `BeforeSave` event.

Answer (score 0):

Try recording a macro while you save your October workbook as November.xlsx and then editing the links in the new workbook to link to October.xlsx.

The raw code will be quite messy but you should be able to edit it to suit other months.

Comment: If you have difficulty modifying the recorded code, then at least you will something to post showing the attempt to create a VBA solution.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I'll try making the macro starting from the Save As event and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

This purely formula-based solution works for me. It is spread across several cells. I imagine you could combine all the formulas in to one very long one in a singe cell, but in my view it's preferable not to. I would just tuck the intermediate cells (cells F12-F17 in my example) away somewhere out of the way.

The formulas:

```
Cell   Formula
----   ---------------------------------------------------------
F12    =CELL("filename",A1)

F13    =MID(F12,FIND("[",F12)+1,FIND("]",F12)-FIND("[",F12)-1)

F14    =LEFT(F13,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(F13,".",
            CHAR(1),LEN(F13)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F13,".",""))))-1)

F15    =TEXT(DATE(2000,MONTH(DATEVALUE("1 " & F14))-1,1),"mmmm")

F16    =F15 & MID(F13,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(F13,".",
            CHAR(1),LEN(F13)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F13,".","")))),LEN(F13))

F17    =SUBSTITUTE(F12,F13,F16)

F18    =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,1,,,F17))
```

The results, assuming the current sheet is saved as `December.xlsx`:

```
Cell:  Value:
-----  ---------------------------------------------------------
F12    C:\Users\user.name\Documents\[December.xlsx]Sheet1
F13    December.xlsx
F14    December
F15    November
F16    November.xlsx
F17    C:\Users\user.name\Documents\[November.xlsx]Sheet1
F18    value from cell A1 in November.xlsx!
```

Notes:

- **F12**    Gets full path of current workbook. May need to manually                   update calcs (press F9) for this cell to refresh
- **F13**    Extracts filename from between '[' and ']' characters
- **F14**    Removes extension (everything after last '.') to get the file's 
                base name (i.e. this month's name)
- **F15**    Geta name of previous month
- **F16**    Appends the extension that was removed earlier, to get filename of
                previous month's sheet.
- **F17**    Substitutes this filename into the current workbook's path.  Here we 
                assume that this month's workbook is saved in the same folder 
                as the previous month's workbook.
- **F18**    Gets value from row 1, column 1 (cell A1) in previous month's sheet